# Файл (каталог) занят другим процессом

Tags: c#

Делаю авто-обновление, и перед распаковкой архива с обновлением, я сделал удаление папки с программой (а после программа удаляла временную с обновлятором), дабы не было ошибок с разархивацией. Но **вылетает всегда ошибка**:

> "**Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят
>   другим процессом**"

Хотя это **каталог**. Сколько не мучился, сколько не гуглил, ничего не нашёл, связанного с каталогами.

Удаляю папку так:

```
DirectoryInfo AppDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(AppPath);
if (AppDirectory.Exists) AppDirectory.Delete(true);
```

Главное, если запустить программу **самому**, а не через

```
Process.Start(TempPath + @"\Updater.exe");
```

То всё **работает** на ура.

Баг платформы? Или фиксится?

Comment: Ну правильно, вы пытаетесь удалить файл запущеной программы в каталоге. Ваш Process еще работает

Comment: Возможно программе требуется некоторое время чтобы закрыться и убрать блокировку директории. Попробуйте добавить задержку перед удалением. Или может у вас программа которую вы пытаетесь удалить остается запущенной. Сложно понять что у вас там происходит.

Comment: Вообще сложно понять. Подробнее пишите какие программы запускаются из каких директорий.

Comment: Попробуйте при запуске updater указать ему WorkingDirectory= TempPath (через перегрузку Start с StartInfo).  Скорее всего по умолчанию текущим каталогом для updater выбирается текущий для родительского процесса, а не temp, и он не может его удалить потому что сам же его использует.

Comment: @PashaPash , А вот описанное вами более похоже на правду, т.к. я написал самописное удаление папки, и оно работает, но при указаниив коде файла update.zip как находящегося в текущей директории, он выдавал ошибку, что файл не найден в каталоге родительской программы.

Answer (score 0):

Предварительно нужно завершить скрытые процессы.

```csharp
foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("process name"))
{
    proc.Kill();
}
```

Comment: Нет. Вообще не то. Никак не помогло.

Comment: @Osid в смысле не то ? данный код подразумевает поиск всех запущенных процессов по именем `process name` - нужно заменить на имя вашего процесса, исполняемого файла БЕЗ РАСШИРЕНИЯ , пример `myProgram.exe` имя процесса `myProgram`, данный код должен исполнятся до удаления изменения файлов.